# Model object state in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model, clone

We are developing an enterprise application which has n number of controllers and views sharing data between them through common service. It is almost complete but we now face a roadblock regarding how to save the previous state of model object.

Actually there is a clear functionality which should return the view and hence the model to the original state before all its data is saved to the database. But since controller is singleton whatever change is made to model that gets retained so there is no way to bring back previous state.

For now we think of deep cloning the original object. But that is quite an overhead. It would be grateful if anyone can provide better approach to accomplish this.

Comment: Eh? You want to persist data at a certain point during the process... Just do that then?

Comment: How to save model data since controller is singleton so any changes to it would persist and any reference to it will reflect the new state. I guess I'm not so clear with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The controller being a singleton is not an issue for persisting data as long as your model object is not an instance variable and it is threadlocal (only used in methods).

So just call a service class method that persists using your preferred mechanism at any point you wish.